# Not able to access connected table in Eloquent when foreignId is different from default

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

Here's the problem: I can't access items property in user object and they are connected in an Eloquent relationship (one user can have multiple items), but I named the foreignId column as customer_id as opposed to user_id default as referenced table is users. When I tried to access items property in blade, here is error that showed up on display:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.user_id' in 'where clause'

select * from `items` where `items`.`user_id` = 3 and `items`.`user_id` is not null

So, it clearly searches for the default foreignId column and not for the one I defined as foreignId for that relationship.
Here's relevant part of my code:

```
Item.php:

public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'customer_id');
}



User.php:

public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
public function get_user($user_name){
        return User::where("user_name",$user_name)->first();
    }


Migration for items table:

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('wine_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('customer_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

UserController.php
...
$user = $user_model->get_user($request->user_name);
            $request->session()->put("user",$user);
...



Blade:

<?php
       $items = session('user')->items;
       $empty_cart = true;
       foreach($items as $item){
       if($wine->id==$item->customer_id){
           $empty_cart = false;
           return;
       }
     }
      var_dump($empty_cart);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually in your `hasMany` relationship, since `user_id` does not exist in the `items` migration.

You need to define the foreign key here (as you did in the Item model) since it appears most likely to be `customer_id` instead.

The error triggers from your blade code here: `session('user')->items;` -- as soon as `items` is accessed.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one and put customer_id only on belongsTo.